# Annoying double value

Tags: c#, floating-point, progress-bar, double, decimal

Ok can anyone explain why the variable offset comes back as 0?
I need to update a progress bar but the value is less than 100 so offset is the value to increase current by and then update the progress bar with the floored value of current but as it comes back 0 it's not updating!

```
double offset = 0.000001;
int hmm = (image.Height * image.Width);
double current = 0;

MessageBox.Show(offset.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(hmm.ToString());
offset = 100 / hmm;// 0.01;// 100 / (image.Height * image.Width) * 10000;

MessageBox.Show(offset.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're performing *integer* division - both `hmm` and `100` are integers. Therefore if `hmm` is greater than 100, it will always give 0 as the result. Convert either operand to a `double` and it'll use floating point arithmetic. For example:

```
double offset = 100.0 / hmm;
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
 offset = 100./hmm;
```

The problem is you're using integer division.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing an integer division between `100` and `hmm`. The result would always be an integer, and you are seeing it produce 0 because `hmm` is greater than `100` in your case.

Try this instead:

```
offset = 100f / hmm; // the trailing f makes 100 a float
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm is an int. Try declaring it as a float or double, or cast it as such when you perform the calculation.

IE.

```
offset = 100 / ((double)hmm);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the last line of code. If you write 100 / hmm the result will be seen as integer value as 100 is an integer. Try using

```
((double)100)/hmm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer division always *drops* the decimal point. Therefore, something like `1 / 100` = .01 would just become 0.